# tab using array change when login and logout

Tags: php, tabs

i am trying to do Tab using arrays but i cannot think of a way to change my login tab to be logout when im login here is my tab script

```
$pages = array (
                 'Home' => 'index.php',
                 'About' => '#',
                 'Contact' => '#',
                 'Register' => 'register.php',
                 'Login' => 'login.php'

        );

        // The page being viewed:
        $this_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

        // Create each menu item:
        foreach ($pages as $k => $v) {

            // Start the item:
            echo '<li';

            // Add the class if it's the current page:
            if ($this_page == $v) echo ' class="selected"';

            // Complete the item:
            echo '><a href="' . $v . '"><span>' . $k . '</span></a></li>
            ';

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have a function called isLoggedIn() which returns true if the user is logged in, or false if he isn't. All you need to do I guess is to just change the isLoggedIn() function in my code to whatever the appropriate function you are using is and you're good to go probably.

You have two ways of doing this.

First one would be to create the links array without neither the login link nor the logout link, and then throw an if statement and push an element onto the array depending on the result.

```
$pages = array (
    'Home' => 'index.php',
    'About' => '#',
    'Contact' => '#',
    'Register' => 'register.php'
);

if(isLoggedIn()) $pages['Login'] => 'login.php';
else $pages['Logout'] => 'logout.php';
```

A second way of doing this is to dynamically load the last element of the list as so:

```
if(isLoggedIn()) {
    $log_link = 'Login';
    $log_href = 'login.php';
}

else {
    $log_link = 'Logout';
    $log_href = 'logout.php';
}

$pages = array (
    'Home' => 'index.php',
    'About' => '#',
    'Contact' => '#',
    'Register' => 'register.php',
    $log_link => $log_href
);
```

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: i im having this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in C:\wamp\www\practice\includes\header.html on line 28

Comment: Can you show me line 28 and a couple of lines before and after it?